# How do I discern between specific NFC tags?

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I am working with NFC/RFID on Android. I have to read cards with RFID, store the information, and trigger an action when previously stored cards are read again.

It seems uid returned by `tag.getId()` are randomized every time I tap a card.

What would be the best way to go about identifying NFC connections? Which information is permanent when it comes to NFC? Phones have IMEI that uniquely identifies a device. Do passive RFID cards have anything similar?

**Edit (also included in comment):** I just downloaded the wakdev NFC Tools app that stdunbar suggested. The app shows that tag type is ISO 14443-3A. Technologies available are NfcA, MifareClassic, and NdefFormattable. Also in the NFC Tools app, my RFID card's serial number does not change every time I tap. I want to access that serial number. The serial number is in the format hh:hh:hh:hh, where each h is a hex digit.

Comment: I've used NFC Tools from wakdev (available for free in Google Play) to help debug this type of stuff.  Yes, virtually all tags should have a unique identifier but it depends at least in part on the tag type.

Comment: What type of tags are you using?

Comment: I just checked with the wakdev NFC Tools app that stdunbar suggested.. The app shows that tag type is ISO 14443-3A. Technologies available are NfcA, MifareClassic, and NdefFormattable. Also in the NFC Tools app, my rfid card's serial number does not change every time I tap. I want to access that serial number. The serial number is in the format hh:hh:hh:hh, where each h is a hex digit.

Comment: It is indeed a duplicate. I just came to the same conclusion elsewhere as suggested in your link. Thank you.